# loosing values in user controls after postback

Tags: asp.net

I have a page that has a user control in it. In the user control text boxes generate dynamically in a place holder and there is a button that will save all of them into the database.
 But here is the problem:
 When i click on save button, first, my page's page load event runs, then  it loads user control, then user control page load event runs. so text boxes loose their content from last page.
 any idea?

Comment: Check for `IsPostBack`.

Comment: then my user control wont be added to the page

Comment: in your user control

Comment: then text boxes wont be added to the user control

Comment: then you have to add text box in `ascx` page directly, and not from code

Comment: this user control is different for the IDs coming from query string.

Answer (score 0):

Within your Page_Load, continue to always generate your textbox controls (regardless of IsPostBack).  However within the control, only set an initial value if `IsPostBack = false`.  That way when IsPostBack is true the textbox will take it's value from the ViewState instead.

Comment: textboxes are also usercontrols